# Not able to connect to slave machine in case of master is down in redis sentinel configuration, all are running in Docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, redis, redis-sentinel

I have 1 master(6379), 1 slave(6380), and 3 sentinels(26379, 26380, 26381) running on docker container master and slave are connected and up even sentinels are giving right information about master-slave.

When I do my query with master and slave both up, it is running fine and I could see(through exposed ports) the same data in both(sync between master and slave is fine).

When I pause master, sentinels act and make slave new master but this time when I try to access redis through my code it is not able to connect and Redis command timed out nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException is thrown.

**docker-compose file**

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=inward
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      #- MYSQL_USER=test
      # You can use whatever password you like
      #- MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
      # Password for root access
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=unroot
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - 3309:3306
  master:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  slave:
    image: redis
    command: >
      bash -c "echo 'port 6380' > slave.conf &&
      echo 'replicaof master 6379' >> slave.conf &&
      cat slave.conf &&
      redis-server slave.conf"
    links:
      - master
    ports:
      - 6380:6380
  sentinel:
    image: redis
    command: >
      bash -c "echo 'port 26379' > sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'dir /tmp' >> sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'sentinel monitor mymaster master 6379 2' >> sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 5000' >> sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'sentinel parallel-syncs mymaster 1' >> sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 5000' >> sentinel.conf &&
      cat sentinel.conf &&
      redis-server sentinel.conf --sentinel"
    links:
      - master
      - slave
    ports:
      - 26379:26379
  sentinel1:
    image: redis
    command: >
      bash -c "echo 'port 26380' > sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'dir /tmp' >> sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'sentinel monitor mymaster master 6379 2' >> sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 5000' >> sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'sentinel parallel-syncs mymaster 1' >> sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 5000' >> sentinel.conf &&
      cat sentinel.conf &&
      redis-server sentinel.conf --sentinel"
    links:
      - master
      - slave
    ports:
      - 26380:26380
  sentinel2:
    image: redis
    command: >
      bash -c "echo 'port 26381' > sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'dir /tmp' >> sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'sentinel monitor mymaster master 6379 2' >> sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 5000' >> sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'sentinel parallel-syncs mymaster 1' >> sentinel.conf &&
      echo 'sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 5000' >> sentinel.conf &&
      cat sentinel.conf &&
      redis-server sentinel.conf --sentinel"
    links:
      - master
      - slave
    ports:
      - 26381:26381
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - master
      - slave
      - sentinel
      - sentinel1
      - sentinel2
    working_dir: /app
    command: [sh, -c, 'mkdir -p ~/logs/; cd /src ; mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=local -DLOG_DIR=/root/logs/ -DLOG_FILE=hubstamper.log']
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - "${HOME}/.m2:/root/.m2"
```

and application.properties file is

```
spring.redis.sentinel.master=mymaster
spring.redis.sentinel.nodes=sentinel:26379,sentinel1:26380,sentinel2:26381
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

`links` is depreciated in docker. Keep all the depending containers in `depends_on:`. Eg.:

Replace

```
links:
      - master
      - slave
```

with this:

```
depends_on:
      - master
      - slave
```

It does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I have tried that also but it did not solve my problem.